# How to add method to AppDelegate.m through a project template definition

Tags: iphone, ios

I cloned and modified Apple's iOS project template and am able to define one of its method as the following:

```
<key>Definitions</key>
<dict>
    <key>___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___AppDelegate.m:applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions</key>
    <string>- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        UIViewController *mainViewController = [[AppMainViewController alloc] init];
                   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

            self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

            return YES;
    }
    </string>
```

The code is generated nicely in the AppDelegate.m
However the following does not generate 'myMethod'

```
<key>___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___AppDelegate.m:myMethod</key>
        <string>- (void)myMethod:(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
        {
              //my code
        }
        </string>
```

How to introduce my own method into the class via the template definition?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean "does *not* generate"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your method is not appearing is that what you are doing is not enough. The templates form a unified hierarchy. You are just giving the definition of a method. You also have to state that the method exists. Look in the templateInfo.plist for Cocoa Touch Application, the ancestor of your template, and you will see where this happens. There is a Nodes array that lists all the possible methods.

Comment: Thanks Matt! After I added the following the method is generated.       <key>Nodes</key>
 <array>
 <string>___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___AppDelegate.m:myMethod</string>
 </array>